# Finding Round Integer

Tags: mathematics, algorithm

An integer is round if it is greater than $0$ and the sum of its digits in decimal representation is a multiple of $10$.
Find an optimal procedure to compute the $N^\text{th}$ smallest round integer.

E.g.
If $N = 2$
 then Answer is $28$
As the first round integer is $19 (1+9 = 10)$ and the second round integer is $28(2+8 = 10)$

*______*
Source: https://www.codechef.com/JUNE19B/problems/KS2

Answer (score 7):

The $N$th round integer is given by

> $$f(N) = 10N + k$$ where $k$ is a single digit and $k \equiv -S(N) \mod 10$ and $S(N)$ is the sum of the digits of $N$.

Proof

> Take any set of digits $S$ and suppose the sum of the digits in $S$ is congruent to $s$ mod $10$. There is **exactly one** digit $x$ which we could add to $S$ to make the overall sum divisible by $10$, that is, essentially, $-s$ mod $10$. 
>  This means that for any integer $N$, there is exactly one digit that we could append to $N$ to make the overall sum of its digits divisible by $10$. Hence, for each $N$, there exists one digit $n$ such that the sum of the digits $10N + n$ is divisible by $10$. This $n$ must be $-S(N) \mod 10$

Example

> Consider finding the $2019$th round number. $$S(2019) = 2 + 0 + 1 + 9 \equiv 2 \mod 10 $$ $$\Rightarrow k \equiv -2 \mod 10 \Rightarrow k=8$$ Hence the $2019$th round number is $20198$.

Comment: damn...this is so elegant.